# Custom error not working in ASP.NET on IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I use IIS 10. In `web.config` I have these settings for default errors:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5.2" />

    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Errors/OtherErrors.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Errors/Error.aspx?type=404&amp;Language=FA" />
    </customErrors>

    <sessionState cookieName="TolueSession1" />
</system.web>
```

And I added this config for custom errors:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="400" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Errors/Error.aspx?type=400&amp;Language=FA" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
           ....
    </httpErrors>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

But I get this error:

> /Errors/Error.aspx?type=404&Language=FA

and the custom error setup is not working.

I want to run custom error for every error.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

> my codes works in local asp.net but my codes do not work on the web

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/error#how-to-add-a-custom-error-page If you scroll down and read the notes carefully, you will see that 400 (and many others) cannot be customized.

Comment: @LexLi tnx,it doesn't work for 404 error either

Answer (score 0):

> **ExecuteURL**
>
> Serves dynamic content (for example, an .asp file) specified in the path attribute for the custom error. If responseMode
> is set to ExecuteURL, the path value has to be a server relative URL.

Source from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/error#how-to-add-a-custom-error-page

Please make sure your custom error page's relative path is set correctly.Assuming your custom error pages are stored in the following path, you need to set the relative path to "/Errors/Error.aspx".

[image]

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
     <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/> 
     <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Errors/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/> 
</httpErrors>
```

> The following HTTP errors can't be customized: 400, 403.9, 411, 414,
> 500, 500.11, 500.14, 500.15, 501, 503, and 505.

But for the 404 error code, the settings of the custom page can work normally. Please try the configuration code I provided, if it still doesn't work, please let me know.